# Adobe cq - background images / CSS

Tags: css, aem

When for example, we would normally add background images into a stylesheet via a class, is it possible in cq for an author to specify an image, and cq itself to amend the CSS to add the class and background image specification.
I guess the other way is for the sling resource to add an inline stylesheet. What's the best method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar in modifying components in CRX(DE) using an inline stylesheet so that their dialogue window has additional fields for users to enter. I added to the image component a field for having a target image selected from the DAM for target when clicked.

You could do something along the lines of this:

Component properties

```
/yoursite/components/content/-yourcomponent-/dialog/items/bgImage (your component tree may vary slightly)

fieldLabel : String = Image to Link to
jcr:primaryType : Name = cq:Widget
name : String = ./bgImage
xtype : String = pathfield
```

Add the following to /yoursite/components/content/-yourcomponent-/yourcomponent.jsp

```
<%
String bgImage = properties.get("bgImage", "");
String cssStyle = "";
if (bgImage != null) {
  cssStyle = "background:url(" + bgImage + ") no-repeat;";
}
%>

<div style="<%= cssStyle %>">
  // Other output here
</div>
```

This is a very rough draft, but you should get the idea.

**Update:** If you wish to add CSS classes externally, and reference them in code. However, you'd still have to append a user-selected image as an inline, or internally.

- In CRX(DE), expand /etc/designs/-yoursite-/styles.css/files in your development/author instance
- Add a new CSS file accordingly, or append your code to an existing file
- The system will merge all CSS files into one huge styles.css file
- styles.css is cached by the system, so changes may not occur immediately based on application settings.

`<div class="imageDiv" style="<%= cssStyle %>"> </div>`

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea on possibly the other way - say we wanted to add a lot of styles (possibly a few of them calculated programmatically from the image, rather than via an author dialog), and therefore wanted to apply them via a class - is it possible to programmatically 'amend' the CSS file to add these classes, or even, is it possible to programmatically create CSS on the fly?

Comment: Updating above answer accordingly.